Successive filters of arbitrary size
I have the dataframe



ID
filter1
filter2




0
False
False


1
False
True


2
False
False


3
True
False


4
False
False


5
False
True


6
True
True


7
True
False


8
True
False


9
False
False


10
False
False


11
False
False


12
False
True



I want to find each sequence with filter1=True and the successive filter2=True
The expected output is:



ID
filter1
filter2
EXPECTED_RESULT
description




0
False
False
False



1
False
True
False
There is no True before in filter1


2
False
False
False



3
True
False
False
The start condition


4
False
False
False



5
False
True
True
Close condition from ID=3


6
True
True
True
In same row


7
True
False
False
Here is the start condition


8
True
False
False
Here is the start condition - we start again


9
False
False
False



10
False
False
False



11
False
False
False



12
False
True
True
Close condition from ID=8




Use m = df['filter1'].cummax() and after that check where the values are equal df['result'] =  m.where(m).eq(df['filter2'])

Just turned @Triky's comment into code:
import pandas as pd

data = [[False, False], 
[False, True], 
[False, False],
[True, False],
[False, False],
[False, True],
[True, True],
[True, False],
[True, False],
[False, False],
[False, False],
[False, False],
[False, True]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["filter1", "filter2"])

m = df['filter1'].cummax()
df['result'] = m.where(m).eq(df['filter2'])
print(df)

Result:
    filter1  filter2  result
0     False    False   False
1     False     True   False
2     False    False   False
3      True    False   False
4     False    False   False
5     False     True    True
6      True     True    True
7      True    False   False
8      True    False   False
9     False    False   False
10    False    False   False
11    False    False   False
12    False     True    True


Code
You can do this by splitting the groups with filter2 column True to the last group member, and leaving filter2 column True only if filter1 column True exists in each group.
grp = df['filter2'].cumsum() - df['filter2']
cond = df['filter1'].groupby(grp).transform('any')
df['result'] = df['filter2'] & cond


chk with new example
import pandas as pd
data = {'filter1': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
        'filter2': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).astype('bool')

grp = df['filter2'].cumsum() - df['filter2']
cond = df['filter1'].groupby(grp).transform('any')
df['result'] = df['filter2'] & cond

df:
   filter1  filter2  result
0    False    False   False
1    False     True   False  <-- not start
2    False    False   False
3     True    False   False
4    False    False   False
5    False     True    True
6     True     True    True
7    False     True   False  <-- not start
8     True    False   False
9    False     True    True

